# Check architecture for Linux and Mac

Tags: c#, linux, macos, mono, .net-2.0

I'm trying to get the architecture of the computer executing my software, and so far it is working nice on Windows, but it fails on Linux and OSX. Let me show my current code:

```
//--Check processor architecture--
string strProcArchi = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE");
string strProcArchiBis = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432");

if((strProcArchi != null && strProcArchi.IndexOf("64") > 0) || (strProcArchiBis != null && strProcArchiBis.IndexOf("64") > 0))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Processor is 64-bit");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Processor is 32-bit");
}
//------
```

Linux and Mac always return "Processor is 32-bit", so I guess that those environment variables are unused outside Windows. I've been googling for a couple of days but can't find anything specific. Any ideas on how to achieve this? I need to load different assets whether the computer that's executing it is 32-bit or 64-bit based, so this check is definitely important.

I'm under .NET 2.0 and I can't use `Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem` or `Environment.Is64BitProcess` since that's a .NET 4.0 feature.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does `Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem` or `Environment.Is64BitProcess` work for you?

Comment: No, sorry, I should've clarified that. I'm under.NET 2.0 and that's a .NET 4.0 feature. But thank you anyway :)

Comment: It's a quite a long time since Macs had 32 bit processors, as you can see [here](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201948).

Comment: @TheDarkKnight I know, but I still need to support them due to publisher requirements.

Comment: Does [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988996/detect-cpu-architecture-32-bit-64-bit-runtime-in-objective-c-mac-os-x) help?

Comment: Mono has dumped its CLR 2.0 (net20/net30/net35 profiles) support, so you should safely use .NET 4 API on it. Don't use such Windows environment variables, as neither macOS nor Linux set them at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To detect bitness of your .NET runtime process (mono process in your case) you can check `IntPtr.Size == 8` and to detect bitness of your processor you can parse the output of `sysctl hw.cpu64bit_capable` command on OSX and the output of `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "flags" | grep " lm "` command on Linux.

Comment: Hi jariq, and thanks. This is of no use to me, since the executable is already 32-bit based, what I need to know is the CPU bitness outside my program.

Comment: @Neper In such case you can parse the output of `sysctl hw.cpu64bit_capable` command on OSX and the output of `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "flags" | grep " lm "` command on Linux.

Comment: Nice, will definitely try that out.

Comment: Could you make your last comment into an answer? I'd like to mark it as Accepted :)